# overridePendingTransition not working

Tags: android, android-intent, transition

I'm trying to implement a transition in my app but overridePendingTransition(anim, anim) is not working correctly.

- I have window transitions enabled
- After debugging the code I can say that the compiler does execute the call but it is NOT shown
- I have tried calling finish() before overridePendingTransition() this does not seem to have any effect

My code is simple and standard:

Starting the intent and calling overridePendingTransition:

```
Intent newsIntent = new Intent(ZPFActivity.this, More2013Activity.class);
startActivity(newsIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_no_move, R.anim.fade);
finish();
```

The start animation should not do anything only the fade animation should have effect.

slide_no_move XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="500"/>
```

fade XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:fillAfter="true">
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention the fact that the activities that I start all **extend** the 'main' activity. Could this be the fact that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I saw it and felt obligated to answer it:

It was a very obscure problem, and it was device related. I was using an iOcean X7 at the time. Later I found out that this Phone was not able to play animations. For some it did not play animations on ANY app.

Answer (score 30):

Try to call the pendingTransition after calling `finish()`, like this:

```
Intent newsIntent = new Intent(ZPFActivity.this, More2013Activity.class);
startActivity(newsIntent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_no_move, R.anim.fade);
```

Comment: I should have added to my question that I've already tried this.

Comment: No problems.
I don't know why it's not working then, sorry :(

Answer (score 28):

If you activate usb debugging mode, it can disable the transitions effects.
Enter Developer options (where you activated debugging mode), find the user's interface section, check if the animation's transition scale have the animations disabled. If so, set it to .5x. Done!

Comment: thank you very much, this worked, although it first seemed to be a strange solution

Answer (score 17):

If you are using android version >= 21 then make the **android:windowActivityTransitions** attribute to **true** in the **style.xml** file in the **values-v21** folder as follows.

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

       <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

   </style>
```

Answer (score 15):

from 6.0 use this method to override the custom animation

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context,R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WhichActivityToOpen.class);
context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 14):

Try using this :

```
    public class More2013Activity extends Activity{
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          overridePendingTransition(R.anim. slide_no_move, R.anim.fade_in);
          setContentView(R.layout.more_activity)
      }
    }
```

instead of your code.

Comment: Just tried to but it didn't work. Please check my edit I forgot to mention the fact that all activities implement the 'main' activity.

Comment: you can test by making your `More2013Activity` to extends `Activity`, not your main one to see if that's the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Go in your device Developer Options, There are three further options windows animation scale, Transition Animation scale and Animation duration scale. Make sure all are not off. This is one of the reason I came across.

Comment: This post was already answered. I had already verified the fact that these were turned on. It was a device specific problem.

Comment: @Tim Kranen, It is not device specific problem for your kind information. Don't miss lead others. It is not my mistake if you picked up wrong answer.

Comment: But this problem WAS device specific. I have tried your solution too, it didn't help. The device simply didn't support these animations.

Answer (score 2):

please check your device is in power saving mode. in power saving mode animations will not work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I had the same problem, I have searched many times for this question, but i didnt checked whether my phone is in power saving mode,  In power saving mode overridePendingTransition will not work, i have changed the mode to normal, now it is working,

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using `overridePendingTransition(anim, anim)` in your `onPause()` method too.
I had the same problem but I solve it by a tiny trick.

1: Define a boolean in your `class` before `onCreate()` method

```
private boolean pendingTransaction = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...
```

2: Set `pendingTransaction` to `false` when you you use `startActivity();`

```
Intent newsIntent = newIntent(ZPFActivity.this,More2013Activity.class);         
 pendingTransaction = false;        
 startActivity(newsIntent);        
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_no_move, R.anim.fade);
```

3: Override the `onPause()` method by doing this.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (pendingTransaction) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_no_move, R.anim.fade);
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

4: Override the `onResume()` method by doing this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    pendingTransaction = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge for me was not with execution, but rather proper conceptualization.

The `overridePendingTransition` method accepts an **enter** animation and an **exit** animation.

The trick to conceptualizing these properly is that **enter** and **exit** will have different meanings depending on WHERE we call `overridePendingTransition`:

- When called from `onResume`, the **current** activity is entering and the **previous** activity (whatever it was) is exiting.
- When called immediately after `startActivity`, the **next** activity (being started) is entering and the **current** activity is exiting.
- When called from `finish`, the **next** activity (whatever it winds up being) is entering and the **current** activity is exiting.

Once I understood these rather weird enter/exit rules, I was able to accomplish proper transitions from anywhere to anywhere.

Hope this helps.