# Add animation to new Activity

Tags: android, transactions, android-activity, android-animation

I am trying to add a transition between activitis, but is not working.

I have been looking here and fix it, but none of the answers worked for me.

Like :

[overridePendingTransition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745079/overridependingtransition-not-working)

[Can I change the Android startActivity() transition animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515264/can-i-change-the-android-startactivity-transition-animation)

[Make new activity appear behind old one during transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294446/android-animation-for-new-activity)

I post my code:

In my MainActivity with one button i set the onclick listener.

```
    cobrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent formasdepago = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Formas_De_Pago.class);
            startActivity(formasdepago);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_in,R.anim.push_out);
        }
    });
```

Push_in.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

      <translate 
          android:fromYDelta="100%p" 
          android:toYDelta="0" 
          android:duration="500"/>
    </set>`

Push_out.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

      <translate 
          android:fromYDelta="0" 
          android:toYDelta="-100%p" 
          android:duration="500"/>
    </set>`

Comment: Do you want to do the animation everytime the Activity is started, or just when called from certain places? If everytime, place your `overridePendingTransition` in the onCreate of the Activity being started.

Comment: I want to make the animation each time you click on the button "cobrar".

Comment: I am trying put overridePendingTransaction in the onCreate!

Comment: Glad you figured that out. I hadn't heard of that before. Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my phone, I had disable this option:

Settings->Developer options -> Transition animation scale