# How to execute my overridePendingTransition?

Tags: android, android-animation

*NB: similar questions are listed at the end of this topic, and you will see I have taken into account their answers and their comments...* However nothing works.

---

I am developing a splash screen for my Android application. This splash screen is in the main activity, and fades out. When it finishes fading, the main activity starts another activity.

## The problem

The problem is that the main activity starts the other one without showing the fading effect.

## Configuration

### Emulator

The emulator uses an AVD cofigured like this: the API level is 27, Android is 8.1 Oreo.

### build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.."
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 27
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

## What i have written to do this fading

I... :

1. Created **MainActivity.java** and put the `startActivity` and `overridePendingTransition` calls inside
2. Created two themes in **AndroidManifest.xml** (one for the main activity, another for the other one). I set `windowActivityTransitions` to `true` in the app's theme.
3. Created a style in **anim/fade_out_home_activity.xml** for the animation (thus for the main activity).
4. Created the other activity (including the new .java, new .xml and an update of the manifest).

### What I have done, in detail

#### MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class), ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out_home_activity, R.anim.fade_out_home_activity);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

#### anim/fade_out_home_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

#### (probably not useful for help) styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

## My question

Do you know why the animation isn't shown (note that maybe it's executed - or not)?

## Similar questions

I already created several topics on how to realize a splash screen animation. Note that I don't want to use `setEnterTransition` etc. ([Why the XML specified transition isn't executed? (or why its specified duration isn't taken account?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237312/why-the-xml-specified-transition-isnt-executed-or-why-its-specified-duration) , the reason is in my (my!) first comment in OP here [How to fade out an Activity's UI, and fade in another Activity's UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234457/how-to-fade-out-an-activitys-ui-and-fade-in-another-activitys-ui) ).

I followed some answers from here: [overridePendingTransition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745079/overridependingtransition-not-working) . Those are taken into account in the above code.

I also added `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle()` as suggested in an answer here: [Android: Activities animations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598296/android-activities-animations-not-working) .

Nothing works, I'm going crazy so much I wasted time doing a simple animation between two activities! At the beginning, I also wanted to execute another animation, when the main activity is started, but I gave up the idea (someone told me it was impossible - you can retrieve this answer or comment in the above links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
    public void onFinish() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class), 
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }

}.start();

}
```

Comment: You see the splash screen, it's fading and, when the fading has finished, the new activity?

Comment: I just used `Handler.postdelayed` before your answer and both work! Is `Handle.postdelayed` more appropriate here?

Comment: That's what my answer on your previous question depicted

Comment: instantly starting the activity oncreate would override the next transition late which wouldn't allow you to see anim